# Python: line highlight on Sublime Text 2 from ipdb

Tags: python, debugging, sublimetext2

for a while I had this option that highlighted the currently executed line on a Python source file open in Sublime Text 2 while debugging from the shell with ipdb.

I don't know if it was a plugin, or an option or something, but I can't find it anymore. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Is [PdbSublimeTextSupport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PdbSublimeTextSupport) what you haven been looking for? And https://gist.github.com/reebalazs/7641029 for a suitable .pdbrc? Though autocompletion seems to be broken with this setup.

Comment: I get a couple of syntax errors, but autocomplete is working for me.. thanks!